# Centering a div with a full width/height border

Tags: jquery, html, css

First off, here's the jfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nuLyq28d/

What I am trying to do is make the white border expand the entire height of the screen and center the content inside the box, both horizontally and vertically. The background will be changing as it will be three images (instead of solid black) changing between each other. So leaving the white border as part of the actual images would be weird. I want it to be separate from the images.

```
<body id="home-page">
<main>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis eros posuere sit, volutpat nec massa sit a ac, amet pede eu justo, suspendisse adipiscing 
                viverra. Amet quisque, justo elit dui orci aliquam praesent, et condimentum nibh. Ultricies cubilia eu fringilla elementum 
                erat, arcu metus dictum id feugiat, ultricies interdum elementum, magna nec urna sit non condimentum a, massa tempus nibh. 
                Eros turpis in erat sed, adipiscing a molestie, eros arcu. Est at est nec augue</p>
    </div>
</main>
```

```
body#home-page
{
background-color: #000000;
}

body#home-page main
{
display: table;
padding: 20px;
width: 88%;
border: 8px solid #FFF;
margin: 20px;
}

body#home-page main div
{
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 50%;
}

body#home-page main div p
{
font-size: 12px;
color:#FFF;
line-height: 1.4;
letter-spacing: 1px; 
}
```

Things I have tried so far include:
- absolute positioning the content. This pushed it outside the border box and looked awful.
- a set height won't work since this needs to be responsive.

I think my only other option at this point is to capture the height of the screen through jQuery and then set the height of the main to that height. But before I do that I was wondering if there was a way to do this through CSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nuLyq28d/2/  You're close.  I added 100% to body and html, as well as the container, and set the main div to display as table-cell.  It's not perfect, but its a dang close CSS solution

Comment: A closer solution: https://jsfiddle.net/nuLyq28d/3/

Comment: @Vaune_X is that second solution you sent with the body, html { height: calc(100% - 8px); } compatible across browsers?

Comment: Calc is supported in most modern browsers.  Backwards compatibility wise, not so much.  http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc

I can help work up a jQuery solution too if you're interested

Answer (score 1):

Vertical alignment acheived in chrome by following code

`height: 100%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;`

For `.main` div, `box-sizing: border-box;` added so that we can use 100% width.

html, body need 100% height.

Here is the updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/afelixj/nuLyq28d/7/

Please check in chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work..:D tested in chrome,firefox,opera,ie..

```css
body#home-page {
 background-color: #000000;
}
body#home-page main {
 left:0px;
 right:0px;
 bottom:0px;
 top:0px;
 position:absolute;
 display: table;
 border: 8px solid #FFF;
 margin: 20px;
}
body#home-page main div {
 text-align:center;
 margin:0 auto;
 vertical-align: middle;
 padding:20%;
}
body#home-page main div p {
 font-size: 12px;
 color:#FFF;
 line-height: 1.4;
 letter-spacing: 1px; 
}
```

```html
<body id="home-page">
<main>
    <div>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis eros posuere sit, volutpat nec massa sit a ac, amet pede eu justo, suspendisse adipiscing 
                viverra. Amet quisque, justo elit dui orci aliquam praesent, et condimentum nibh. Ultricies cubilia eu fringilla elementum 
                erat, arcu metus dictum id feugiat, ultricies interdum elementum, magna nec urna sit non condimentum a, massa tempus nibh. 
                Eros turpis in erat sed, adipiscing a molestie, eros arcu. Est at est nec augue</p>
    </div>
</main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the other two answers, but without all the `position:absolute;` / `display:flex;` nonsense (This answer is cross-browser friendly):

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;    
}
html, body {
    height:100%;
    width: 100%; 
    margin:0;
}
body#home-page {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding:20px;
}
body#home-page main {
    display: table;
    padding: 20px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 8px solid #FFF;
    height:100%;
}
body#home-page main div {
    text-align: center;
    display: table-row;
}
body#home-page main div p {
    display: table-cell;
    font-size: 12px;
    color:#FFF;
    line-height: 1.4;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<body id="home-page">
    <main>
        <div>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, duis eros posuere sit, volutpat nec massa sit a ac, amet pede eu justo, suspendisse adipiscing viverra. Amet quisque, justo elit dui orci aliquam praesent, et condimentum nibh. Ultricies cubilia eu fringilla elementum erat, arcu metus dictum id feugiat, ultricies interdum elementum, magna nec urna sit non condimentum a, massa tempus nibh. Eros turpis in erat sed, adipiscing a molestie, eros arcu. Est at est nec augue</p>
        </div>
    </main>
</body>
```

I set this:

```
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;    
}
```

so we can just throw 100% heights and widths at any element without having to calculate padding or border.

We then just tell the `html` and `body` to be full page size and give our elements a table/table-cell layout.